# Best practice for joining MySQL tables in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two models like this in my Django project.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductSubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture = models.FileField()
```

Of course a product can have 2 or more pictures.
How can I get a all products with all related every single image in my view and pass the result as a context to the template?

I searched and tried these:
`prefetch_related`,
`select_related`,
`raw sql query`
and couple of suggested ways, but cannot get the result.

Comment: Post the code for your current view.

Comment: PS: Looks like you use 2 models for category & sub-category. It's not the proper way. You'd need to manage a hierarchy of Categories first and then have a ManyToMany relation from Product to Category.

Comment: this is my curretn ciew and just can get product without images
`def all_products(request, sub_category_id):
    all_products = Product.objects.all().filter(sub_category=sub_category_id)
    context = {
        'all_products': all_products,
        'page_title': ProductSubCategory.objects.get(pk=sub_category_id),
    }
    return render(request, 'gita/products.html', context)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `prefetch_related` to optimise the query

```
Product.objects.filter(sub_category = sub_category_id).prefetch_related('productimage_set')
```

Then, in the template

```
{% for image in product.productimage_set %} 
display image here
{% endfor %}
```

You may alternately set a `related_name` in the foreign-key, like

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_images")
```

and then in the view,

```
Product.objects.filter(sub_category = sub_category_id).prefetch_related('product_images')
```

end then in the template

```
{% for image in product.product_images %} 
    display image here
 {% endfor %}
```

Refer [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Thanks for you response but return 0 for productimages_set. I use **{{ product.productimage_set|length }}** in my template to count the result images for every product and it was 0. I'm sure that I have images in my media folder with correct address in database.

Comment: Show the code for your template. (Instead of adding the code as comment, edit your original post and add to the bottom)

Comment: dear @art06 I'm so sorry. that was my wrong. your code was right. I check my database. the foreign keys not set. I guess it was because of my changes and migrations. Thank you so much